# No more stack on crash trace since iOS 5.0 with Xcode 4.5

Tags: xcode, debugging, crash

I got this problem since few months.

When I test my game on cocos2D with iOS 4.3 simulator I got a stack trace on crash. All is ok.

But on 5.0, 5.1, 6.0 simulators/device no more stack trace...
Just an error from the main.m file.
So annoying.

Just test with this type of error

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray array];
id obj = [arr objectAtIndex:0];
```

I already added an exeception breackpoint but nothing changed.

Can you help me please?

Thanks.

EDIT:

The crash details appears on the debug navigator only.

Screenshot of the crash on iOS 5
http://imageshack.us/f/202/capturedcran20121002140.png/

Screenshot of the crash on iOS 4.3
http://imageshack.us/f/706/capturedcran20121002141.png/

Comment: What does the error message exactly say? Where does it appear? What does it show in the debug navigator (the view on the left when the debug icon is selected)?

Comment: I added 2 screenshots with all details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found that:
http://www.oramind.com/index.php/articles/182-ios-5-xcode-backtrace

It's worked for me.